# find next elements but not in order having same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to find elements which have `.item` class but they are not in order. Below is sample code.

```
<ul>
  <li class="item">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li class="item">list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li class="item">list item 6</li>
</ul>
```

I want to traverse each `li` element having only `.item` class on key-press event. I have tried .nextAll() getting all elements but it takes much time to produce resultsets as I have huge li elements.

```
var siblingsElements = $('.item').nextAll(); // Takes much time
```

How can i achieve the result ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to get `.item` element or next all element after `.item` ?

Comment: @NishitMaheta , I want to get all elements having .item class

Comment: `$('.item')` it self contain all element have class item . if you want to get all element  objects then use  ` $('.item').each(function(){})`

Comment: @NishitMaheta I would modify the question a bit.

Comment: @NishitMaheta modified question

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati did you try my solution ?

Comment: try this   var siblingsElements = $('li.item')

Comment: what you want to do after get all `item` element ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite code with Native JS, it works much faster

```
var items = $('ul')[0].getElementsByClassName('item');

items = $(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('li.item').each(function(){ 
   --your code here--
  })
```

Because this will find only li having class "item" instead of all dom elements having class "item" which may speed up your process.